# Two Y-scales in pyqtgraph (twinx-like)

Tags: python, plot, pyqtgraph

How can I generate a plot with two Y-scales in `pyqtgraph`?

I also need the two in different colors (corresponding to lines' colors).

[image]

In matplotlib it can be done using `twinx`, as in [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html).

If there's no way to do it with a single plot object, perhaps there's a way to overlay a plot (with y-axis on right side) on another one (with the y-axis on left)?

Comment: stripped matplotlib tag as the answer you want is un-related to mpl.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See `pyqtgraph/examples/MultiplePlotAxes.py`.

The solution is just what you described--overlay two PlotItems.

Comment: Thanks for your work on the development of pyqtgraph, Luke. I noticed in the example file that this feature will eventually be built into PlotItem. Do you still have plans to add this feature? The solution in the example file works well for my purposes either way.

Comment: For my fellow lazy people, here's a link  https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/pyqtgraph/examples/MultiplePlotAxes.py

Answer (score 6):

Here is some code that I think shows a practical example of what it is you are after.  This is an expansion of two pyqtgraph examples: PlotSpeedTest.py and MultiplePlotAxes.py.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
pg.setConfigOption('background', '#c7c7c7')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', '#000000')
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

p = pg.plot()
p.setXRange(0,10)
p.setYRange(-10,10)
p.setWindowTitle('Current-Voltage')
p.setLabel('bottom', 'Bias', units='V', **{'font-size':'20pt'})
p.getAxis('bottom').setPen(pg.mkPen(color='#000000', width=3))
p.setLabel('left', 'Current', units='A',
            color='#c4380d', **{'font-size':'20pt'})
p.getAxis('left').setPen(pg.mkPen(color='#c4380d', width=3))
curve = p.plot(x=[], y=[], pen=pg.mkPen(color='#c4380d'))
p.showAxis('right')
p.setLabel('right', 'Dynamic Resistance', units="<font>&Omega;</font>",
            color='#025b94', **{'font-size':'20pt'})
p.getAxis('right').setPen(pg.mkPen(color='#025b94', width=3))

p2 = pg.ViewBox()
p.scene().addItem(p2)
p.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
p2.setXLink(p)
p2.setYRange(-10,10)

curve2 = pg.PlotCurveItem(pen=pg.mkPen(color='#025b94', width=1))
p2.addItem(curve2)

def updateViews():
    global p2
    p2.setGeometry(p.getViewBox().sceneBoundingRect())
    p2.linkedViewChanged(p.getViewBox(), p2.XAxis)

updateViews()
p.getViewBox().sigResized.connect(updateViews)

x = np.arange(0, 10.01,0.01)
data = 5+np.sin(30*x)
data2 = -5+np.cos(30*x)
ptr = 0
lastTime = time()
fps = None

def update():
    global p, x, curve, data, curve2, data2, ptr, lastTime, fps
    if ptr < len(x):
        curve.setData(x=x[:ptr], y=data[:ptr])
        curve2.setData(x=x[:ptr], y=data2[:ptr])
        ptr += 1
        now = time()
        dt = now - lastTime
        lastTime = now
        if fps is None:
            fps = 1.0/dt
        else:
            s = np.clip(dt*3., 0, 1)
            fps = fps * (1-s) + (1.0/dt) * s
        p.setTitle('%0.2f fps' % fps)
    else:
        ptr = 0
    app.processEvents()  ## force complete redraw for every plot.  Try commenting out to see if a different in speed occurs.
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```